# Can I use R Notebooks as R package vignettes?

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown, rnotebook

I know I can use `Rmd` to build package vignettes but want to know if it is possible to R Notebooks more specifically to make package vignettes. If so, is there anything different I need to write R Notebooks as package vignettes? I am using the latest versions of RStudio and `devtools` to write this package.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answers to your two questions are yes and no, respectively.

The key to understanding R Notebooks is that they are not a different *kind* of file; as the [documentation](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/r_notebooks.html) says:

> Any R Markdown document can be used as a notebook

Since vignettes *are* R Markdown documents (with `output: rmarkdown::html_vignette` in their YAML header block), they can therefore be used as R Notebooks.

So if R Notebooks aren't a different kind of file, what are they?

Again, the documentation is succinct:

> A notebook can therefore be thought of as a special execution mode for R Markdown documents

In other words, it just changes your *interaction* with the file. Those changes mostly have to do with making the code development process more interactive and dynamic. Perhaps most significant:

- **Interactive code execution:** you can execute lines or chunks as desired (compared to batch mode rendering of the entire R Markdown document)
- **Embedding of code output:** You can see the results of your interactive coding session displayed inside the text editing buffer of the file, and those results are updated as you run, change, and re-run code.
- **Notebook files:** This is a bit more complex and isn't necessarily relevant to vignettes, but bears mentioning. When you save a `.Rmd` file which has `output: rmarkdown::html_notebook` in the YAML header block, *another* file is created in the same directory, and which has the file extension `.nb.html`. This "Notebook file" stores the output of all code chunks, in whatever state you left them when you saved. It's useful for two reasons. First, when you re-open the related `.Rmd` file those outputs are re-loaded for you to see without needing to re-run any code (although this is also handled in a hidden way for other output types). Second, you can open these `.nb.html` files directly in any web browser and they'll display a rendered .html version of the notebook's state. This feature makes them useful for sharing, and the "render-as-you-go" nature saves you needing to hit `knit` every time you want to view an intermediate state of an unfinished notebook.

When editing in RStudio, all .Rmd documents are treated like R Notebooks (no matter what their `output:` field says), so you don't need to do anything and it won't affect your vignette-building process.

I'm not sure whether vignettes can take advantage of the "Notebook files" feature by adding *both* `output: rmarkdown::html_vignette` *and* `output: rmarkdown::html_notebook` to their YAML header blocks. I gave it a try but it didn't seem to work.